# Office 365 Excel, Receiving Error code 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error. Related to code too long

Tags: excel, vba

Code exceeded max size. Looking through this site it was mentioned to split up the code in multiple procedures. I tried this but it stops running after the first procedure is run. Below is reduced code for example. Thank you!

```
Sub Button31_Click()

Call Proc1
Call Proc2
Call Proc3

End Sub

Sub Proc1()

X = Workbooks("BDSubmittal.xlsm").Worksheets("database").Cells(3, 1).Value 
Y = X + 3
For I = 4 To Y
If ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 3).Value = Workbooks("BDSubmittal.xlsm").Worksheets("database").Cells(I, 1).Value Then
    RESPONSE = MsgBox("OVERWRITE EXISTING SUBMITTAL", vbYesNo)
    If RESPONSE = vbYes Then
        X = I
        GoTo LINE1
    Else
        X = I + 1
        GoTo LINE1
    End If
Else: X = Y + 1
End If
Next I
LINE1:
Workbooks("BDSubmittal.xlsm").Worksheets("database").Cells(3, 5) = X
Workbooks("BDSubmittal.xlsm").Worksheets("database").Cells(X, 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 
3).Value 
Workbooks("BDSubmittal.xlsm").Worksheets("database").Cells(X, 2).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 
3).Value 
Workbooks("BDSubmittal.xlsm").Worksheets("database").Cells(X, 3).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 
3).Value 

End Sub
Sub Proc2()  
Workbooks("BDSubmittal.xlsm").Worksheets("database").Cells(X, 105).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(168,  
3).Value  
Workbooks("BDSubmittal.xlsm").Worksheets("database").Cells(X, 106).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(168, 
5).Value  
Workbooks("BDSubmittal.xlsm").Worksheets("database").Cells(X, 107).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(168, 
7).Value 

End Sub
Sub Proc3()
Workbooks("BDSubmittal.xlsm").Worksheets("database").Cells(X, 417).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(640, 
3).Value
Workbooks("BDSubmittal.xlsm").Worksheets("database").Cells(X, 418).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(640, 
5).Value '2
Workbooks("BDSubmittal.xlsm").Worksheets("database").Cells(X, 419).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(640, 
7).Value '3
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you could use a loop.

Comment: ...and some worksheet/range variables

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I'm new at this and I don't know know how to loop or incorporate a range in the code. I was hoping there was a simple line I missed. Can you please help with this? Thank you!

Comment: The sheet "Database" Range is A4:AGQ. Just needs to paste to the correct row or next sequential available row with a new entry.

Comment: What is the name of the workbook where this code is located? What is the name of `ActiveSheet` and the name of its workbook? What is the maximum number expected in cell `A3` of worksheet `database`?

Comment: Workbook name is BDSubmittal.xlsm, ActiveSheet is Submittal, workbook is BDSubmittal, The max number in database sheet is the formula COUNT(A4:A5000)

Comment: In case my last edit did not take, here it is. Workbook name is BDSubmittal.xlsm, ActiveSheet is Submittal, workbook is BDSubmittal, The max number in cell A3 in the database sheet is the formula COUNT(A4:A5000)

Comment: In the code above Worksheets("database").Cells(3, 1) refers to E3 in the database sheet and is the last row entered.